# Twitter Bootstrap div invisible beyond 768px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I started to learn twitter bootstrap and created very simple layout.

As I change the width of the browser, the two divs in  'row become invisible when the width of the browser goes below 768px. Otherwise the divs are on top of each other.

I want to show the divs without any margins and most importantly, visible !

Here is [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XHkn159OzIOgHVqDAMxG?p=preview).

Comment: Have you tried putting any content in the 2 `divs` to help you see what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the head section. since changing width of the browser beyond an amount you need a style for both

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <style type=text/css>
  .container{
    width:100% !important;
    }
    .row div{
      width:100%;
      margin:0px !important;
      padding:0px !important;
      }
  </style>
    <link data-require="twitter-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="twitter-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link data-require="twitter-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
    <link data-require="twitter-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
    <script data-require="twitter-bootstrap@*" data-semver="2.3.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span 3 red" style="height : 100px"></div>
        <div class="span 9 green" style="height : 100px"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

now div's dont dissapear and no margin also there when you resize.

Answer (score 0):

Your div class has a space between span and the digit.
It should be more like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12 red" style="height : 100px"></div>
        <div class="span12 green" style="height : 100px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap is made on 12 column grid span12 will fill the container but it will have a margin.

If you want it to go all the way across the screen with no margin, don't use span or a container:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="red" style="height : 100px"></div>
    <div class="green" style="height : 100px"></div>
</div>
```

Typical when an element has no margin it would have a container for the content:

```
 <div class=" red" style="height : 100px">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="span12 green" style="height : 100px"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="green" style="height : 100px">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="span12 red" style="height : 100px"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5o0inY0R89U2eUS41oVF?p=preview) example

Also, if you are just starting to learn bootstrap I would recommend you learn [v3.0](http://getbootstrap.com/) instead of v2.3.1.
Might as well learn the most resent version, as there are some differences that won't translate between versions.